# I am trying to be able to open a text prompt and take the input as the url how would i do that?

Tags: bookmarklet

I want to be able to input the URL I want to use into a text box and have to take me to that website, how would I do that?

```
javascript:(function() {document.body.innerHTML+='<iframe style=\"width: 25%;border: 3px solid black; z-index: 100000000000; position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%;\" src=\"https://sample.com">%27;})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`window.prompt()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) if you want the user to input a value.

```js
let url = window.prompt("Select the url","https://example.com/");

document.body.innerHTML+='<iframe style=\"width: 25%;border: 3px solid black; z-index: 100000000000; position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%;\" src=\"' + url + '\">';
```